# Is $x^2=y^2$ a symmetric relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$R=\{(x,y):x^2=y^2\}$ and I have to determine whether its an equivalence relation.

I found that it's reflexive but for the symmetry part I got confused as $x=y$ is sometimes said to be symmetric others not so I don't know what to take it as.

Comment: I don't know where you read about that $x=y$ relation, but if $x=y$ then $y=x$, so that relation is certainly symmetric.

Comment: A relation $R$ on a set $X$ is said to be *symmetric* if for all $a, b \in X$ such that $aRb$, then $bRa$, so you are being asked to determine if $x^2 = y^2$ implies that $y^2 = x^2$.

Comment: It's neither until you specify the domain of the relation.

Comment: Shortcut: equivalence relations (on any set $X$) are exactly the ones you can describe as "$x \mathrel R y$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$" for some function $f$ on $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly if $x^2=y^2$ then $y^2=x^2$, so it is symmetric. It is also transitive because if $x^2=y^2$ and $y^2=z^2$, then $x^2=z^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can even replace taking squares with an arbitrary function. Namely, if $X$ is a set, $Y$ is a second set, and $f\colon X\to Y$ is a function, then define $x\sim x'$ iff $f(x)=f(x')$. In other words, $R = \{ (x,x') \in X\times X \mid f(x)=f(x')\}$. This is an equivalence relation:

- $x\sim x$ because $f(x)=f(x)$.
- $x\sim x'$ implies that $f(x)=f(x')$, so $f(x')=f(x)$, thus $x'\sim x$.
- $x\sim x'$ and $x'\sim x''$ imply that $f(x)=f(x')$ and $f(x')=f(x'')$, so $f(x)=f(x'')$ and $x\sim x''$.

The corresponding partition is the partition of $X$ by level sets of $f$. It doesn't get any more geometric than that.